# sklearn KernelDensity "atol" and "rtol" default=0, what does it mean?

Tags: kernel-density

The parameters "atol" and "rtol" default is 0, in sklearn.neighbors.KernelDensity class. What does this mean?
Does it mean it uses all the data points to calculate the likelihood?
What will happen when they are not set to 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation of sklearn.

> atol : *float*, default=0
> The desired absolute tolerance of the result. A larger tolerance will generally lead to faster execution.

> rtol : *float*, default=0
> The desired relative tolerance of the result. A larger tolerance will generally lead to faster execution.

Intuitively, it means when sklearn calculating the kernel density, the program might stop earlier before finding optimal mean square error. It will allow some range of error, but faster. It's a balance of time and accuracy. You can try what range of atol/rtol you can accept when you are on the developing stage so you don't need to wait so long when testing the code.